# Several case when's with output on same row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having issues with a pretty complicated postgreSQL query that I can briefly sum up as follows:

I have a set of costumers who buy apples, oranges, or both. I also know each date of each purchase. What I'd like is the date of the first purchase for each customer and each fruit.

To do this, I use the following query:

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE WHEN fruitType = 'apple' then min(purchaseDate)
ELSE null END AS appleFirstPurchaseDate
, CASE WHEN fruitType = 'orange' then min(purchaseDate)
ELSE null END AS orangeFirstPurchaseDate
FROM fruitPurchases
GROUP BY fruitType
```

I also have this version (I don't know which one is better for this problem):

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE WHEN fruitType = 'apple' then min(purchaseDate) over(partition by fruitType) 
ELSE null END AS appleFirstPurchaseDate
, CASE WHEN fruitType = 'orange' then min(purchaseDate) over(partition by fruitType)
ELSE null END AS orangeFirstPurchaseDate
FROM fruitPurchases
```

Both give the same result and, when the customer buys only oranges or only apples, it works fine. However, when they've already bought both, I get this for one same customer:

```
appleFirstPurchaseDate  orangeFirstPurchaseDate
----------------------  -----------------------
       2017-05-03                [NULL]
         [NULL]                2016-11-25
```

While the result I'm dreaming of is:

```
appleFirstPurchaseDate  orangeFirstPurchaseDate
----------------------  -----------------------
       2017-05-03              2016-11-25
```

I also checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809426/sql-case-when-on-same-row) (the first of the 3 options) that suggests the use of the MAX function but, because of my MIN function, I get this error message: "aggregate functions calls cannot be nested".

I am vaguely aware that a subquery could solve this problem but, given the whole messy code that I'm working on, I'd rather get a solution that doesn't add new FROM clauses and that would keep using CASE WHEN's. If impossible, I'd be happy with any solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'apple') as apple,
    min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'orange') as orange,
    customer
from fruitPurchases
group by customer
```

Comment: Yeeeaaah it now works fine :) I didn't know this FILTER function but I'll definitely keep using it! Thank you!