# Concatenation with FILTER clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

This question follows [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291359/several-case-whens-with-output-on-same-row).

I now have this code:

```
select
    min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'apple') as appleFirstPurchaseDate,
    min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'orange') as orangeFirstPurchaseDate,
    customer
from fruitPurchases
group by customer
```

Which gives the following output:

```
appleFirstPurchaseDate  orangeFirstPurchaseDate
----------------------  -----------------------
       2017-05-03              2016-11-25
```

You should also know that each piece of fruit has an ID. With this ID, I'd like to create two keys: one that concatenates the fruit ID with the `appleFirstPurchaseDate` and the other one that concatenates the fruit ID with the `orangeFirstPurchaseDate`

Therefore I tried this:

```
select
    fruitId || '-' || min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'apple') as appleKey,
    min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'apple') as apple,
    fruitId || '-' || min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'orange') as orangeKey,
    min(purchaseDate) filter (where fruitType = 'orange') as orange,
    customer
from fruitPurchases
group by customer, fruitId
```

But when a customer has already bought apples as well as oranges, it unfortunately gives me this:

```
  appleKey        appleFirstPurchaseDate    orangeKey    orangeFirstPurchaseDate
  --------        ----------------------    ---------    -----------------------
283-2017-05-03          2017-05-03           [NULL]             [NULL]
   [NULL]                 [NULL]          322-2016-11-25      2016-11-25
```

While I would like this:

```
  appleKey        appleFirstPurchaseDate    orangeKey    orangeFirstPurchaseDate
  --------        ----------------------    ---------    -----------------------
283-2017-05-03          2017-05-03       322-2016-11-25        2016-11-25
```

Last piece of information: an earlier `FirstPurchaseDate` does not imply a lower `fruitID`.

Comment: It would help to provide your version of Postgres, the table definition and some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of a "greatest-per-group" problem, followed by "pivoting".

General assumptions:

- All involved columns are defined `NOT NULL` - or there are problem with sorting and concatenation.
- `(customer, fruidType, purchaseDate)` is ***unique*** - or you need to define rules how to break ties.
- You want just ***two*** fruits in the result.

The **basic problem** in your query: you only want `customer` in the `GROUP BY` clause, since you want *one* row per customer. Not `customer, fruitid` which produces one row *per combination* of `customer` and `fruitid`.

But there is no built-in aggregate function to retrieve, in a single step,
*the `fruitID` from the same row that also holds the earliest `purchaseDate`* for each `(customer, fruidType)`.

You *could* make your query work by *appending* the `fruitID` (instead of prepending) because the concatenated `text` would still sort with the earliest date first, but that's very ugly and needlessly slow:

```
SELECT customer
     , min(purchaseDate || '-' || fruitId) FILTER (WHERE fruitType = 'apple')  AS appleKey
                       , min(purchaseDate) FILTER (WHERE fruitType = 'apple')  AS apple
     , min(purchaseDate || '-' || fruitId) FILTER (WHERE fruitType = 'orange') AS orangeKey
                       , min(purchaseDate) FILTER (WHERE fruitType = 'orange') AS orange
     , customer
FROM   fruitPurchases
GROUP  BY customer;
```

I wouldn't be caught using *that*.

There are the related [window function `first_value()` and `last_value()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html), but those don't aggregate. And you cannot use the `FILTER` clause, which is only for aggregate function. So you would need an extra query level, and it's simpler to just use the window function `row_number()` instead to mark the first row for each group in a subquery or CTE ...

[@Gordon made it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295521/939860) with reversed frame definitions for the window function. Consider this simplified, completed, and optimized version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer)
       customer
     , first_value(fruitId || '-' || purchaseDate) OVER a AS appleKey
     , first_value(purchaseDate)                   OVER a AS appleFirstPurchaseDate
     , first_value(fruitId || '-' || purchaseDate) OVER o AS orangeKey
     , first_value(purchaseDate)                   OVER o AS orangeFirstPurchaseDate
FROM  (SELECT * FROM fruitPurchases WHERE fruitType IN ('apple', 'orange')) sub
WINDOW a AS (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY fruittype ASC , purchaseDate)
     , o AS (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY fruittype DESC, purchaseDate);
```

But this should be **faster**:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer, fruitType)
          customer, fruitType, fruitId || '-' || purchaseDate AS key, purchaseDate
   FROM   fruitPurchases
   WHERE  fruitType IN ('apple', 'orange')
   ORDER  BY customer, fruitType, purchaseDate
   )
SELECT customer
     , a.key          AS appleKey
     , a.purchaseDate AS appleFirstPurchaseDate
     , o.key          AS orangeKey
     , a.purchaseDate AS orangeFirstPurchaseDate
FROM   cte a
JOIN   cte o USING (customer)
WHERE  a.fruitType = 'apple'
AND    o.fruitType = 'orange';
```

All it needs to excel is an **index** on `(customer, fruitType, purchaseDate)` - or on `(customer, fruitType, purchaseDate, fruitId)` if your table allows ***index-only scans***. Details depend on undisclosed information. Related:

- [How does PostgreSQL perform ORDER BY if a b-tree index is built on that field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576669/how-does-postgresql-perform-order-by-if-a-b-tree-index-is-built-on-that-field/31577208#31577208)

The CTE computes the *greatest per group* with `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Depending on actual data distribution there may be even faster techniques:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

The outer `SELECT` is a simplistic *pivoting* technique. Works for any number of fruits.

The same using said window function `row_number()` in the CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT customer, fruitType, fruitId || '-' || purchaseDate AS key, purchaseDate
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer, fruitType ORDER BY purchaseDate) AS rn
   FROM   fruitPurchases
   WHERE  fruitType IN ('apple', 'orange')
   )
SELECT customer
     , a.key          AS appleKey
     , a.purchaseDate AS appleFirstPurchaseDate
     , o.key          AS orangeKey
     , a.purchaseDate AS orangeFirstPurchaseDate
FROM   cte a
JOIN   cte o USING (customer, rn)
WHERE  a.rn = 1
AND    a.fruitType = 'apple'
AND    o.fruitType = 'orange';
```

***dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=afe1d14609bed8e835bb15005332a497)***

But I would seriously consider [normalizing your DB design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) first, which would make the task simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this easier with window functions:

```
select distinct customer,
       first_value(fruitId || '-' purchaseDate) filter (where fruittype = 'apple') over (partition by customer order by purchaseDate) as appleKey,
       first_value(fruitId || '-' purchaseDate) filter (where fruittype = 'orange') over (partition by customer order by purchaseDate) as orangeKey
from fruitPurchases;
```

You can also write this as:

```
select distinct customer,
       first_value(case when fruittype = 'apple' then fruitId || '-' || purchaseDate end) over (partition by customer order by (fruittype = 'apple')::int desc, purchaseDate) as appleKey,
       first_value(case when fruittype = 'orange' then fruitId || '-' || purchaseDate end) over (partition by customer order by (fruittype = 'orange')::int desc, purchaseDate) as orangeKey
from fruitPurchases;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/6124) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I get the following error message: "FILTER is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions". Besides, how is this supposed to yield the minimum of the different purchaseDates?

Comment: Gordon, neither the syntax, nor the logic work out in the 2nd query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . For the second, one, I just don't know what I was thinking.  It is fixed now.

Comment: Now it works! `CASE` is redundant with the new frame definition. And performance might be optimized. I added a variant to my answer. (And the 1st query is still illegal - no `FILTER` for genuine window functions.)